# Picasso HTTP 504 Error when I have already added permission and cleartext http

Tags: android, kotlin

It's just a simple load image from uri, i know about what cleartexthttp does and I have added it, also I have added internet permission but still picasso gives me

```
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R0]+1348ms HTTP 504
```

I'm using emulator API 29

I've added `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` in build.gradle

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.my.first_android_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FirstAndroidApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.my.first_android_app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)

        Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true)
        Picasso.get()
            .load("https://via.placeholder.com/200x200")
            .resize(200, 200)
            .into(imageView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to uninstall the app, and build it again, now it works